# Multiplication of Integers in Textfield - Xcode 4.4

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4, xcode4.2, xcode4.3

I am trying to multiply the integer values in three different text fields.

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UITextField *textField2;
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UITextField *textField3;
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UILabel *total;
```

I am trying to display the product in a UILabel. Can somebody please help with the implementation? Thanks, so much!

Answer (score 0):

to display the product in the UILabel, set the label text this way (assuming the textFields all contain ints):

```
total.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i", (textField.text.intValue * textField2.text.intValue * textField3.text.intValue)];
```

you might want to put this in a separate method so you can call it from anywhere, like whenever the user updates the textFields with new numbers

Comment: Should use `float`s rather than `int`s as the entered values or the answer could include decimals.

Comment: post says specifically they are looking to multiply integer values.